# R: Faster Minimum Column Value Over Multiple Matricies?

Tags: r

I have a very tall integer matrix (mat) and a sparse binary vector (v) of equal row length. I want to find the minimum value in all columns of mat where v==1.

Here are several possible solutions:

```
mat <- matrix(as.integer(runif(100000*100,0,2^31)),nrow=100000,ncol=100)
v<-(rbinom(100000,1,.01))

a<-apply(v*mat,2, function(x) min(x[x>0]))
b<-apply(mat,2,function(x) min(x[v==1]))
c<-sapply(subset(data.frame(mat),v==1), min)
```

These all work fine, and on my machine solution c seems fastest (an admittedly older,slower MacBook). But if I have a function that feeds unique sets of v, the computation time scales linearly with the number of sets. So a large number of unique sets (>10,000) will take hours to process.

Any ideas on how to do such an operation faster, or is this as fast as I can go?

Comment: `sapply(as.data.frame(mat[as.logical(v), ]), min)` would be a little faster than c

Comment: `matrixStats::colMins(mat[as.logical(v),])`

Comment: @Khashaa - Thanks. This is the fastest solution suggested thus far.

 system.time(matrixStats::colMins(mat[as.logical(v),]))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.008   0.000   0.008

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that subsetting and then calling `apply` gains a lot, given that `v` is almost always 0:

```
system.time(b<-apply(mat[as.logical(v),],2, min))
#  user  system elapsed 
# 0.012   0.000   0.013
 system.time(a<-apply(v*mat,2, function(x) min(x[x>0])))
#  user  system elapsed 
# 0.628   0.019   0.649 
identical(a,b)
#[1] TRUE
```

I dropped also the `x[x>0]`, since it appears that `mat` is always greater than 0.

Comment: Isn't this what @rawr suggested?

Comment: @DavidArenburg  rawr suggested sapply on data.frame which is slightly faster than apply on a matrix

Comment: @DavidArenburg  ops, I really missed that comment, very sorry. Feel free to downvote this answer (I really deserve it)!

Comment: I'm actually the only one that upvoted it. Though you deserve another one for the good sarcasm- I deserved it.